# Download file in IE11 get error "'Uint8Array' is undefined"

Tags: javascript, download, blob, internet-explorer-11

I am creating a application in which I am downloading a file. For this I get response from java class in js and download this response.For this my java code is -

```
@ApiOperation(value = "",
            notes = "")
@Path("/getProjectJSONTODRAW/{implementation}")
@GET
@Timed
public Response getProjectJSONTODRAW(@PathParam("implementation") String implementation) {
        File file = new File(path+File.separator+fileName);
        InputStream inputStream =null;
        String mimeType =null;
        if (!file.exists()) {
            String errorMessage = "Sorry. The file you are looking for does not exist";
            log.info(errorMessage);
        }else {
            mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {
                log.info("mimetype is not detectable, will take default for the file "+file.getName());
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            try {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return Response
                .ok(inputStream, mimeType)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"")
                .header("Content-Length", file.length())
                .build();
}
```

And in JS code is -

```
     $http.get('/api/1/explore/getProjectJSONTODRAW/implementation', {
                         responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                     })
                     .success(function(response) {
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        var fileName = "abc.pdf";
                        var mimeType = "application/pdf";
                        var blob = new Blob([response], {
                           type: mimeType
                        }),
                        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = fileName;
                        var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                        if (isIE) {
                           a.style.cssText = "display: none;"
                           window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
                        } else {
                           a.style = "display: none";
                           a.click();
                           window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                        }
                   }).catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                   });
}
```

This give me error at

> var blob = new Blob([response], {type: mimeType})

**Error is - "'Uint8Array' is undefined"** and my IE version is - **IE11**

Comment: `Uint8Array` is listed as defined at ie10+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array. Are there any other errors logged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My angular version is 1.2.26 and Uint8Array is supported in later version of angular 1.5
and add

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If `Blob` does not throw an error you can use `responseType: "blob"`.