# InternetExplorer 11 "'uint8array' is undefined"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, download, blob

I have a download method that is working fine with firefox. When I tried same with IE-11. It does nothing. In further investigation found that while creating blob from arrayBuffer it's throw error for "Uint8Array is undefined". I read some forum where its clear mentioned that IE-11 supports UInt8Array [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array) but according to my code it's seems that it does support.
What should I do to fix the issue - Can it fixed by adding specific js? or else

I am using following js code

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
var fileName = decodeURI($scope.downloadedFileName);
var blob = new Blob([response], {
  type: file.mime_type
});
url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.href = url;
a.download = $scope.downloadedFileName;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file in IE11 get error “'Uint8Array' is undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316539/download-file-in-ie11-get-error-uint8array-is-undefined)

Comment: What occurs when you request resource as a `Blob`?